# Reading @ARGV array input as a string followed by a file list

Tags: perl

I am reading .fasta format files from `@ARGV` input with `<>` construction. The problem is, that first array element has to be just string value, and all others are .fasta files. How should I use first array element as a string and ignore it/jump to the second element at the same time using `<>` construction without any errors(`<>` is necessary to use in my excercise).

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The diamond operator works from the `@ARGV` array, so just `shift` off the first element of `@ARGV` before using `<>`:

```
my $first = shift(@ARGV);

while (<>) {
    # ...
}
```

Or, since `shift` works on `@ARGV` by default when it's used outside of a subroutine, just this:

```
my $first = shift;
```